# Error: 'You are not authorized to perform the requested action' when trying to create a warehouse

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, dashdb, cloudant-sdp

I'm trying to create a dashDB warehouse from Cloudant.  I have provided my IBM ID for Bluemix and Cloudant appears to have logged me on ok, however when I try to create the warehouse I get the following error:

```
Error: provision_dynamite_warehouse: 
   cloudant_user=****, 
   bluemix_user=****@****, 
   error: {
      u'user_error_message': u'You are not authorized to perform the requested action', 
      u'error_code': 10003, u'internal_error_message': u'CF-NotAuthorized'
   }
```

As a test, I have successfully logged into bluemix using the same credentials and instantiated a dashDB service.

What does this error 'actually' mean?  How do I resolve or debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudant is available in different regions as is Bluemix.  When you create a warehouse in Cloudant, the SDP decides which Bluemix region to create the dashDB instance.

In the question, I stated that I had successfully created a dashDB instance.  However, I created that instance in a different bluemix region (US) to the region SDP was trying to use (UK).  When I logged into bluemix and selected the UK region and tried to create a warehouse, I ran into the following error:

[image]

By fixing the above issue, I was able to create a warehouse in dashDB from Cloudant using the SDP.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option to use an existing dashDB instance. Since you say you were able to create it manually on Bluemix you should try creating the warehouse to that newly created dashDB.